# The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dispose, dbcontext

I have a login page in my project that the users can login using it as you can see here :

```
public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        private IUserRepository _iuserRepository;
        public LoginController(IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            _iuserRepository = userRepository;
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string email, string password, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (_iuserRepository.CheckAuth(email, password))
            {

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, true);
                if (shouldRedirect(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }


                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new {Area = "FAdmin"});

            }
            else
            {

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }



        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LogOut()
        {
            DomainClass.CMS.User user = _iuserRepository.FindByEmail(User.Identity.Name).First();
            user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
            _iuserRepository.Save();

            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login", new { Area = "FAdmin" });
        }
```

the first time when i try to login it works fine but after log out,when i am trying to login again i got this error :

```
 The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
```

Here you can see my user interface and repository :

```
 public class UserRepository:IUserRepository
    {
       public CMSDataContext _ctx;
        public UserRepository (CMSDataContext ctx)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
        }
        public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
        {
           return _ctx.Users;
        }

        public bool Save()
        {
            try
            {
                return _ctx.SaveChanges() > 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO log this error
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool AddUser(User newUser)
        {
            try
            {
                _ctx.Users.Add(newUser);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO log this error
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool Delete(User deletedUser)
        {
            try
            {
                _ctx.Users.Remove(deletedUser);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO log this error
                return false;
            }
        }


        public bool Edit(User UpdatedValue)
        {
            try
            {
                _ctx.Entry(UpdatedValue).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO log this error
                return false;
            }
        }


        public IQueryable<User> Search(string Value)
        {
            return _ctx.Users.Where(i => i.Fullname.Contains(Value));

        }

        public IQueryable<User> FindById(int Id)
        {
            return _ctx.Users.Where(i => i.Id == Id);
        }


        public string[] ReturnRole(string Email)
        {

                    string[] res = new string[1];

                    //res[0] = FindByEmail(Email).First().Permission;
                 //   res[0] = "administrator";//member
                    User a=_ctx.Users.Where(i => i.Email == Email).ToList().First();
                    res[0] = a.Permission;
                    return res;

        }


        public IQueryable<User> FindByEmail(string Email)
        {
            return _ctx.Users.Where(i => i.Email == Email);
        }


        public bool CheckAuth(string Email, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_ctx.Users.Where(i => i.Email == Email && i.Password == password && i.Enable=="فعال").Count() == 1)
                    return true;
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO log this error
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my inteface:

```
  public interface  IUserRepository
    {
        IQueryable<User> GetUsers();
        bool Save();
        bool AddUser(User newUser);
        bool Delete(User deletedUser);
        bool Edit(User UpdatedValue);
        IQueryable<User> Search(string Value);
        IQueryable<User> FindById(int Id);
        IQueryable<User> FindByEmail(string Email);
        bool CheckAuth(string Email,string password);
       string[] ReturnRole(string Email);
    }
```

here is my dbcontext :

```
  public class CMSDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public CMSDataContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            Database.SetInitializer(
                new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<CMSDataContext, CMSMigrationsConfiguration>()
                );
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<News> Newses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CompanyMember> CompnayMembers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Gallery> Galleries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Goal> Goals { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Partner> Partners { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SlideShow> Slideshows { get; set; }
        //--------------------------lizing part domain class
        public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GroupFile> GroupFiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RequestFile> RequestFiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RequestComment> RequestComments { get; set; }

    }
```

My ninject

```
using Core.CMS;
using Inf.CMS;
using InfCMSDataLayer;
using Lizing.Inf;
using Lizing.Repository;
using Repository.CMS;
using RepositoryCMS;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MTBCO.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(MTBCO.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace MTBCO.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<CMSDataContext>().To<CMSDataContext>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<INewsRepository>().To<NewsRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IConfigurationRepository>().To<ConfigurationRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IGoalRepository>().To<GoalRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IPartnerRepository>().To<PartnerRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<ICalenderRepository>().To<CalenderRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<ISlideshowRepository>().To<SlideshowRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IProjectRepository>().To<ProjectRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IGalleryRepository>().To<GalleryRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<ICompanyMemberRepository>().To<CompanyMemberRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<ICommentRepository>().To<CommentRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IPageRepository>().To<PageRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IMenuRepository>().To<MenuRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IGroupRepository>().To<GroupRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IRequestRepository>().To<RequestRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IRequestFileRepository>().To<RequestFileRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IGroupFileRepository>().To<GroupFileRepository>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IRequestCommentRepository>().To<RequestCommentRepository>().InRequestScope();





        }        
    }
}
```

My stacktrce

```
[InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +762
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator() +28
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +52
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +369
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   Repository.CMS.UserRepository.ReturnRole(String Email) +348
   MTBCO.MyRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String email) +11
   System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +9625187
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) +197
   System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +96
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +446
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +302
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +381
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +317
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +71
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +249
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I finally find the point that the error happened in `userrepository` .why ?

```
 public string[] ReturnRole(string Email)
        {

                    string[] res = new string[1];

                    //res[0] = FindByEmail(Email).First().Permission;
                 //   res[0] = "administrator";//member
                    User a=_ctx.Users.Where(i => i.Email == Email).ToList().First();
                    res[0] = a.Permission;
                    return res;

        }
```

Comment: it works correctly in localhost but not in my host

Comment: Where are you hosting the the application?

Comment: what you mean  where you are hosting?

Comment: could you show your Login action method and where is your code od creation DBContext located at your controller.

Comment: @StepUp as you can see i put the login controller in the first line of my post,as you can see i inject my repository using ninject

Comment: Show the code of your AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Placing the .First() inside the FindByEmail method and changing its return type to User should resolve this. It should only ever return a single user anyway, and I think that the context is disposed after calling FindByEmail() and before .First(), so when EF tries to execute the query, the connection is already closed.

Comment: @JB06 thank you for your comment but it doesn't work .i got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is related to registering types in IoC container. What IoC container are you using? How do you register CMSDataContext? Maybe you should use something like InstancePerRequest in AutoFac?

Comment: I added details to my post please take a look

Comment: Could you paste whole Ninject class?

Comment: Configuration looks well. You can use kernel.Bind<CMSDataContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope() instead of kernel.Bind<CMSDataContext>().To<CMSDataContext>().InRequestScope(). Maybe you use methods from repository in view or in filter? IUserRepository exposes IQueryable interfaces so you adhere the execution. Try to add the execution to all of these methods in repository (.ToList() or .FirstOrDefault()).

Comment: So i added the execution in view not in repository ,i think it makes to load extra data

Comment: I find the point of error ,could you please give me why this line returns that error?

Comment: I think that DbContext in repository was disposed but you still had IQueryable query in controller to execute. When you invoked FindByEmail(Email).First() EF tried to execute query but DbContext already has been disposed. Maybe you invoke ReturnRole method in authorization attribute? If so, that's the reason of error.

Comment: Yes you are right the reason of the error ,do you have a solution

Comment: As i said before, don't expose IQueryable interface from your repository. There are multiple problems with returning IQueryable from repository methods (testing, caching, disposing). I always execute queries inside my repositories (e.g. .ToList(), .First()).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After replacing in Ninject module

```
        Bind<Context>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

with

```
        Bind<Context>().ToSelf();
```

Context started to work properly